# Chnage DateFormat in Logic apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, azure-logic-app-standard

There is a date field in my logic app which i am getting data from finops connector.
[image]

In JSON assigning the field.
After Parsing Json and create a csv table assinging like this
[image]

Is there a way for me to format the date using formatDateTime in any of the steps above ?

Thanks,
Vivek

Comment: So you know the expression, have you had a go? You can use the expression anywhere you can use the pill.

Comment: Yes I know the expression but in the expression i cannot reference the Date filed above.

Comment: Help me understand why not though. You should be able to.

Comment: I am getting this error In function 'formatDateTime', the value provided for date time string '' was not valid. The datetime string must match ISO 8601 format.'.

Comment: Ok, so can you show us the value of that field? It’ll be in the log somewhere.

Comment: The Input date looks like this 2022-10-18T12:00:00Z

Comment: It should format, can you show us the expression you use to format the date?

Comment: formatDateTime(item()['InvoiceDate'],'dd.MM.YYYY')

Comment: Bizarre, if you've given me the correct value for the `InvoiceDate` when it goes in, it works for me, also, you need to use `dd.MM.yyyy` (small y's) to get the year.  Just thinking though, have you checked all `InvoiceDate`'s in your array?  Are any of them null?

Comment: Now that you mention it I am looking from one record perspective and in array i have some null values which i have joined from multiple sources and places a common csv structure. Do you have any idea what to be passed instead on empty string in remaining InvoiceDate

Comment: Well ... that's really a decision for yourself.  Take LogicApps out of it, what would you do with the data where the invoice date is null?

Comment: Thank you very much I might have been struck there looking from wrong prespective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you may have an issue with null values in your array.

You need to check every item and make sure the `invoiceDate` field contains a valid value.

Something like this will help you if you don't filter them out ...

```
if(equals(item()['invoiceDate'],null),'',formatDateTime(item()['invoiceDate'], 'dd.MM.yyyy'))
```

... but you will need to decide on the business logic with those items that do have a null invoice date.